# How to custom sort in a Python list?

Tags: python

I have a Python list as follows,

```
demo= {'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}
```

How can I sort this list with id attribute?

I have tried

```
sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x.id)   # sort by id
```

but it failed.

Expected output as follows:

```
{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you expect that result? It seems not sorted..

Comment: Your input data is *not* a list (missing `[..]`), and you failed to mention what error message you got (*but fails* is not an error description). Your expected output makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code fails with an `AttributeError` because you are trying to do a lookup of `id` in a `dict` object, which doesn't have one. You need to access the desired dictionary key:

```
sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x['id'])
```

However, that will fail with a `KeyError` if at least one entry in the list does not have the `id` key. In that case, you can use:

```
sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x.get("id"))
```

Optionally you can use a default value in the `get`, if you wish to put all the entries with no `id` above or below the rest. In this case, the following would send entries with no `id` to the bottom:

sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x.get("id", "99"))

---

It may also happen that you have an `id` like `12#10` and you don't want it to be between `12#1` and `12#2`. To solve that problem, you need to split the `id` and have a more complex sorting function.

```
def get_values(item):
    return [int(x) for x in item['id'].split('#')]

def compare(a, b):
    a = get_values(a)
    b = get_values(b)
    if not a[0] == b[0]:
        return a[0] - b[0]
    return a[1] - b[1]
```

Then you call `sorted` using that comparison function:

```
sorted(demo, cmp=compare)
```

Or in Python 3, where `cmp` has been eliminated:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
sorted(demo, key=cmp_to_key(compare))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `demo` is the list (note the brackets and commas)

```
demo= [{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
       {'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'},
       {'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
       {'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
       {'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}]
```

Then you could sort it by `id` with:

```
sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x['id'])
```

For example:

```
In [5]: sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x['id']) 
Out[5]: 
[{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
 {'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
 {'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
 {'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'},
 {'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
demo= [{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'},
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}]

a = sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x['id'])

for el in a:
    print el
```

gives

```
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}
{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}
```

which is sorted by id.

### Sort by multiple attributes

```
demo= [{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'},
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}]

a = sorted(demo, key=lambda x: (x['id'], x['age']))

for el in a:
    print el
```

gives

```
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}
```

which is first sorted by id and then by age (ascending).

Alternatively, if you want to sort ASC by  id and DESC by age, you can make something like this:

```
demo= [{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'},
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}]

a = sorted(demo, key=lambda x: (x['id'], -x['age']))

for el in a:
    print el
```

which gives

```
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}
{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not inlude a list, you need to have `[]` around your dictionaries. I have fixed that for you:

```
>>> demo= [{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'},
{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'},
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'},
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}]
>>> sorted(demo, key=lambda x: x['id'])
[{'age': 67, 'id': '12#1'}, 
{'age': 90, 'id': '12#2'}, 
{'age': 56, 'id': '12#2'}, 
{'age': 34, 'id': '12#2'}, 
{'age': 12, 'id': '12#3'}]
```